# usage:jag java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in wso2 apim 1.10 and DAS 3.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have followed below procedure for publishing statistics. I have setup in desktop with standalone configurations and no clustering, database is installed.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+REST+Client

I'm getting below error in the apim logs and not able to see statistcis.

ERROR - usage:jag java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
Index: 0, Size: 0

ERROR - usage:jag java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
Index: 0, Size: 0

[error i see in statistics page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulAd2.png)

i have searched old stackoverflow tickets but couldn't find the correct solution. can anybody please help on this

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already reported and you can find the relevant jira in [[1]](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DAS-404). Please note that WSO2 API Manager 1.10 only supports WSO2 DAS 3.0.X versions. Based on the jira this issue is already fixed in WSO2 DAS 3.1.0. I am not sure why you are getting this in DAS 3.1.0. Anyway, you cannot use DAS 3.1.0 with APIM 1.10 due to other complexities.

The root cause for this issue when you start the server in the daemon mode the Spark variables are not loaded and Spark cluster does not function properly. To avoid this you can start the DAS servers in nohup mode as follows.

> nohup ./wso2server.sh &

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have few questions more: 1) How do i make it run on windows? 2) Is there any place or method where wso2 apim stores api calls, logs where I can extract it without installing other DAS server?is there any document present from apim metrics point of view for analyzing the data and alerting, because i'm not able to co-relate with apim metrics from wso2 das documentation. (sorry i'm new to apim and das server)

Comment: In windows you can use YAJSW - (https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service). You can integrate google analytics with APIM to get stats without using WSO2 DAS. - (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Integrating+with+Google+Analytics). APIM 2.x onwards alerts have been introduced in the product. (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+Alerts) For APIM 1.10.0 you can find the analytics docs in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Working+with+Statistics